# JMS Receiver Application Down (Wildfly)

Tags: jms

I have a special question

I develop a ServletContextListener to create message listeners on queue in application startup and stop (receiver,session, and connection) message listeners in application destrpyed like below

```
public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

private static JMSQueue updateIssueOrderApprovalQueue;
private static JMSQueue rejectIssueRequestQueue;

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent p1) {
    updateIssueOrderApprovalQueue = IssueOrderApprovalOperationsListener.registerUpdateIssueOrderApprovalQueueListener();
    rejectIssueRequestQueue = RejectIssueRequestOperationsListener.rejectIssueRequestQueueListener();
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    try{
        if(updateIssueOrderApprovalQueue != null)
            updateIssueOrderApprovalQueue.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        if(rejectIssueRequestQueue != null)
            rejectIssueRequestQueue.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

the code works fine and the no. of consumers in Wildfly console decreased when i stop the application 
But the server console contain some strange errors as below

`13:56:21,315 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002)) Exception in thread "Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002)" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise$2
13:56:21,316 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:589)
13:56:21,317 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess(DefaultPromise.java:397)
13:56:21,317 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:151)
13:56:21,317 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
13:56:21,318 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002)) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$2 from [Module "deployment.Finance.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
13:56:21,318 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
13:56:21,318 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
13:56:21,318 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
13:56:21,320 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
13:56:21,320 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    ... 4 more
13:56:21,749 WARN  [io.netty.util.ThreadDeathWatcher] (threadDeathWatcher-2-1) Thread death watcher task raised an exception:: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/buffer/PoolArena$1
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.freeChunk(PoolArena.java:266)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache.freeEntry(PoolThreadCache.java:444)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:414)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:406)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:263)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:254)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.free0(PoolThreadCache.java:235)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.access$000(PoolThreadCache.java:38)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$1.run(PoolThreadCache.java:64)
    at io.netty.util.ThreadDeathWatcher$Watcher.notifyWatchees(ThreadDeathWatcher.java:195)
    at io.netty.util.ThreadDeathWatcher$Watcher.run(ThreadDeathWatcher.java:130)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$1 from [Module "deployment.Finance.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 13 more
13:56:22,556 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002)) Exception in thread "Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002)" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise$2
13:56:22,556 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:589)
13:56:22,556 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess(DefaultPromise.java:397)
13:56:22,557 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:151)
13:56:22,557 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
13:56:22,747 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-8 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002)) Exception in thread "Thread-8 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002)" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise$2
13:56:22,748 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-8 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:589)
13:56:22,748 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-8 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess(DefaultPromise.java:397)
13:56:22,748 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-8 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:151)
13:56:22,749 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-8 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
13:56:23,101 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002)) Exception in thread "Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002)" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultPromise$2
13:56:23,102 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:589)
13:56:23,102 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess(DefaultPromise.java:397)
13:56:23,102 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:151)
13:56:23,102 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads-805579002))    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
13:56:28,757 WARN  [io.netty.util.ThreadDeathWatcher] (threadDeathWatcher-2-1) Thread death watcher task raised an exception:: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/buffer/PoolArena$1
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.freeChunk(PoolArena.java:266)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache.freeEntry(PoolThreadCache.java:444)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:414)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$MemoryRegionCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:406)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:263)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.free(PoolThreadCache.java:254)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.free0(PoolThreadCache.java:235)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache.access$000(PoolThreadCache.java:38)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolThreadCache$1.run(PoolThreadCache.java:64)
    at io.netty.util.ThreadDeathWatcher$Watcher.notifyWatchees(ThreadDeathWatcher.java:195)
    at io.netty.util.ThreadDeathWatcher$Watcher.run(ThreadDeathWatcher.java:130)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)`

I think that server still have live thread waiting for a message to call my listeners and when he check for my listener, thread don't find the listener because  i already close the jms connection between server and application.

Note: Error only printed in log once after i disable(stop) my application deployment in the server.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this..facing the same issue.

Comment: No, I ignored the problem as its related to the application server

Comment: same is happening when I an undeploying the app in Jboss.. Is is safe to ignore this?

Comment: I am not sure. All I got that it happens because the server has a thread that keeps consumer up. This thread not closed properly when the application is undeployed from the server and I cannot get a reference to this thread to close it during application down so I assumed that issue related to the application server.

Comment: I have upgraded the activemq version latest version..seems to have solved my issue